# What does POST (canceled) in cypress mean?

Tags: cypress

I wrote a test case in cypress. The test works, but sometimes it logs the following:

```
(XHR) POST (canceled) /user/...
```

Then it continues. Does this mean, that the server canceled the request or did cypress canceled it?